# How to reduce tag waiting time in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click a specific link in the web page with specific text.
However, if the link is not present, it takes 1 minute before it prints out element is not found. How do I reduce this time for faster execution?

```
try{

if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()='specifictext']/@href")).isEmpty())
{
By loadMoreComment=By.linkText("specifictext");
driver.findElement(loadMoreComment).click();
}
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
logger.warn("Specific text not found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That would only happen because of implicit waits. Look at below definition

> **Implicit Waits**
>
> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

So you should lower that implicit wait if you want an early failure

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The above call before your code, will ensure the failure happens within 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use Implicit wait to reduce tag waiting time.

> Implicit waits are used to provide a waiting time (say 30 seconds)
>   between each consecutive test steps across the entire test script or
>   program. Next step only executed when the 30 Seconds (or whatever time
>   is given is elapsed) after execution of previous step.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```